# Filter sheets column based on cell with multiple values

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a spells info list for a dungeons and dragons google sheets and a basic filter by values does not meet my needs. Filter by values would work if I was only going to have a single value in the cell, but I was going to be recording both class and spell level, so Wizard 1 would be W1 and Druid 1 would be D1. The reason why filter by values does not work is because a spell belongs on different spell lists at different levels. So if I was to make a multiclass character, I would like to be able to say show all that contain any of (W1, W2, C1) because I am a 3rd level wizard and 1st level cleric.

I know I could do this by having each class with its own column as I was doing this before, but I was looking for a more complete solution.

| Spell Name | Spell Lists |
| --- | --- |
| Mage Armor | W1, S1 |
| Resistance | C0, D0, W0, S0 |
| Shield of Faith | C1, D1 |

Choosing only W0 would give

| Spell Name | Spell Lists (W0) |
| --- | --- |
| Resistance | C0, D0, W0, S0 |

Comment: How about a sample sheet....?

Comment: @RemcoE33 Are these samples good enough?

Answer (score 0):

I did this using the QUERY() function although I am sure there are other solutions

```
=query(A1:B4, "SELECT A, B WHERE LOWER(B) LIKE LOWER('%"&JOIN("%') OR LOWER(B) LIKE LOWER('%", SPLIT(B11, ","))&"%')", 1)
```

This is on a sample sheet I created

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbLOjTdzISICTKyUp_jK6gZbQCt-OwtDYYy3HNJygeE/edit#gid=1358975023

Answer (score 0):

With your current sample data `FILTER()` would give you desired result.

```
=FILTER(A2:B4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("W0",B2:B4)))
```

[image]